# Timeout individual threads of cached thread pool

Tags: multithreading, threadpool

I want to use a thread pool in a web application which should support large number of users concurrently (~3000 users). I am invoking a web service in a separate thread which I am executing using a thread pool. Whenever the web service is not able to send the response, the thread gets stuck. So I want to stop/timeout the thread after 150 Milli-seconds. This is what I am doing right now:

the custom thread:

```
public class RetrieveDocTask implements Runnable {
public void run() {
    //gather variables
    //invoke webservice
}}
```

The filter which executes the threads:

```
public class DocFilter implements Filter {
private static ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    RetrieveDocTask task=new RetrieveDocTask();
    executor.execute(task);
}}
```

I browsed the internet for solutions and none of them worked for me. Some said use Future and callable while some asked to create ThreadPoolExecutor and specify the timeout. Don't know why it was not working. 
Also, will it be fine to use cached pool executor for large number of users. I am new to this and need to implement it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed a Future is what you need here. Suppose that your class RetriveDoc returns a string actually.

```
 private static final class RetrieveDoc implements Callable<String>{
      @Override
      public String call() throws Exception {
          //do some computation and retirieve doc
          return "DocAsString";
      }
 }


 ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
 Future<String> futureResponse = service.submit(new RetrieveDoc());
 //this will blokc for only 150 milliseconds
 String response = null;
 try{
      response = futureResponse.get(150, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
 } catch(TimeoutException e){
     System.out.println("TimeoutException happended");
 }

 if(response == null){
      //do something
 }
```

Comment: For testing, I placed String response = futureResponse.get(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES); When I put a break point in call method and let it wait for more than five minutes, I was expecting a TimeoutException. But that did not happen. Also, do I need to put these two statements in a synchronized block. 
Future<String> futureResponse = service.submit(new RetrieveDoc());
      //this will blokc for only 150 milliseconds
      String response = futureResponse.get(150, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

Comment: @nevin this will not work in debug. And no, that does not need to go in a synchronized block.

Comment: I was still having doubts and that is why I did not accept at that time. I have accepted it now but I am still not sure about it. What if a thread comes to this statement Future<String> futureResponse = service.submit(new RetrieveDoc()); and then its paused and some other thread starts running on that filter. So next time when that thread gets a chance to call futureResponse.get it will get timeout exception unneccessarily.

Comment: @nevin Im sorry but I did not understand what you mean. If ThreadA submits the task, *it will carry on executing the next lines of code*, the task that it has submitted is executed by a Thread from the Thread pool. For example 'Main' thread calls service.submit(SomeCallable). That's it! Main *will not execute the task*. Some other thread will -> one from the ExecutorService that you created, that has a thread pool in the backend.

Comment: I think I got what you said. I placed some loggers and found out that the main thread is waiting for the response to come from futureResponse.get. This is defeating my purpose. I want the main thread to carry on and the other thread to run for 150 milli seconds and stop/expire on its own.

Comment: @nevin then you have to start a new thread that will wait for the reuslt